# How to handle AuthExceptions when thrown from Amplify.Auth.signIn()?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, aws-amplify

Currently trying to implement a basic login function with Amplify and wanted to include error handling. I tried calling Amplify.Auth.signIn() with a valid username and incorrect password.
I, of course, get an error.

Here's the code:

```
static signIn(String username, String password) async {
try {
  SignInResult signInResult =
      await Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password);
} on AuthException catch (e) {
  print('eror signing in');
  print(e.message);}
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
W/CognitoUserSession(20580): CognitoUserSession is not valid because idToken is null.
D/AWSMobileClient(20580): Sending password.
D/AWSMobileClient(20580): Using USER_SRP_AUTH for flow type.
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580): NotAuthorizedException
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580): NotAuthorizedException{message=Failed since user is not authorized., cause=com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 7bb8f3c6-3d17-4286-979f-1578951a8b4e), recoverySuggestion=Check whether the given values are correct and the user is authorized to perform the operation.}
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.util.CognitoAuthExceptionConverter.lookup(CognitoAuthExceptionConverter.java:103)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin$5.onError(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.java:427)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.call(InternalCallback.java:77)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback.onError(InternalCallback.java:67)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6$1.onFailure(AWSMobileClient.java:1331)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$6.onFailure(CognitoUser.java:1158)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$23.run(CognitoUser.java:2952)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser$24.run(CognitoUser.java:3002)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.continuations.AuthenticationContinuation.continueTask(AuthenticationContinuation.java:147)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6$1.getAuthenticationDetails(AWSMobileClient.java:1295)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.getSession(CognitoUser.java:1035)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient$6.run(AWSMobileClient.java:1228)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobile.client.internal.InternalCallback$1.run(InternalCallback.java:101)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580): Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.NotAuthorizedException: Incorrect username or password. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: 7bb8f3c6-3d17-4286-979f-1578951a8b4e)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:420)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:229)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:6779)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.respondToAuthChallenge(AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient.java:5263)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoidentityprovider.CognitoUser.respondToChallenge(CognitoUser.java:2923)
E/amplify:flutter:auth_cognito(20580):  ... 7 more
I/flutter (20580): eror sign in
I/flutter (20580): Failed since user is not authorized.
```

Yes, the username that I input is 100% correct because signing in with the correct password worked.

Now my question is:

1. What does this "Failed since user is not authorized." exactly mean?
2. How do I extract the message "Incorrect username or password" to let the user know what the issue might be?
3. Is there a better way to handle this kind of exceptions?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I've faced same problem. Are you fixed this problem?